# What does "Life gets in the way!" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Could you help me understand what "Life gets in the way!" means? Thanks.

Comment: Sure. I'll do it now! :-)

Comment: ["Life is what happens to you while you're busy making other plans."](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080315150812AAwCM66). From [John Lennon, "Beautiful Boy"](http://www.quotationspage.com/quote/571.html). General Reference/Not Constructive.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: everybody should read  and understand this quote at least once in life. A very profound meaning!

Comment: Did you say "wife gets in the way"?

Comment: I'm shocked to see that my question is closed and moreover the reason for that is closed! It's just the question of a foreigner.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It normally means that the routine of day-to-day living throws up obstacles to doing whatever it is that the speaker wants to do.

For instance:

> I want to go to dance classes, but there's never enough time in the evenings, after work and cooking. Life gets in the way!

Comment: is it something like: "Routine of day-to-day living hampers me from doing things I'd like to do"? If so, then everything is clear.

Comment: Yes, although I think you mean *hampers* or *hinders*. It also covers non-routine matters, such as occasional emergencies - e.g. "I was going to go to the dance class, but the car needed an oil change that day. Life just keeps getting in the way!"

Comment: I have a lot of questions about English language, but I wouldn't like to become annoying and try to rarely ask questions. :-)

Comment: @Chris's sister: Don't take it to heart if some of your questions get closed for being General Reference - what you don't know, you don't know. But the site exists to answer (on-topic) questions, so just keep asking, and only worry if people *downvote* the question (that usually means you didn't ask "properly", so there should be something you can do to improve your next question).

Comment: @Chris'ssister: One more hint for you, when you want to ask what something means, include very specific information about (a) where you found the quote, (b) what you learned when you did some basic research, and (c) why you are still confused. (Look how [one user did just that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80861); notice how that user has **10,000 points**.)

Comment: @J.R.: I need no point, but answers.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: You're missing my point, I think. Usually, you'll get better answers if you ask a better question. Here's why: (1) the rest of the community will take your questions more seriously; (2) there will be less chance of confusion about what you're really asking about, (3) there's a much better chance your question will stay open for more than a few hours before being closed; (4) a thoughtful and upvoted question may movitate some to think harder.  Upvotes don't just bring "points," they attract the some of the keener minds on this site. It's called _reputation_ for a reason.

Comment: @J.R.: honestly, I wouldn't group the questions into good questions and bad questions because this is a nonsense in my view. The above question is a good question for me since it helps me understand what its meaning is. (1) the community knows that many foreign people join the site and such questions may be asked (2) my question is very concise (3) "closed as not constructive" - isn't it constructive that the question helps me understand things?

Comment: @J.R.: (4)  According to this reasoning one should "suffer" a bit until manage to gather some points such that his\her questions aren't closed that fast and the keener minds on this site will pay more attention on his\her questions. How about if I ask only one question and nothing more?

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Do what you will. I was only trying to offer a suggestion that might've helped you out in the future. And, for the record, I don't mean that a higher rep gets you more attention, I mean a **question** with 5+ upvotes may get more attention than one with two or three downvotes.

Comment: @J.R.: anyway, thanks for your time and the explanations offered.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: I'll offer one last thought. Take a look at [this screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Hzup7.png), then ask yourself, "If I only had a few minutes to look at a question or two, which ones would I look at? The ones with six upvotes? Or the ones with two downvotes?" Maybe that explains why the questions with more upvotes have significantly more views than the downvoted questions, even though they were all asked around the same time. Something to think about.

Comment: @J.R.: I'd try to look at all of them because behind the question there is a person that needs some help. Honestly, I'd look at them in the order they come on the screen. As regards the upvotes and the downvotes there is an interesting thing. The question here is:"Should I treat better/worse a question because some users decided so by upvotes\downvotes?" Well, the answer is definitely NO since I need to think with my brain and not to copy the pattern/behaviour of a group that decide to massively upvote or downvote a certain question. Behind the questions are persons that are not perfect.

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Hmmm... You never have an appointment you need to go to? Homework that needs to be done? Kids that need help with something? You always have time to look at *every* question? Your philosophical saccharine isn't resonating with me – I **do** treat questions differently, but not because I don't have a brain, or because I subscribe to "group think,", or don't care about people needing help; rather, I've learned to trust the community to upvote stimulating, thought-provoking questions, and downvote those where people ask questions flippantly with no attention paid to quality.

Comment: @J.R.: thought-provoking questions? are there non-thought-provoking questions? I really don't know what "quality" means in terms of asking questions. He was always glad for the fact that we were interested in improving things and encouraged us to ask any question. Our teacher never told us that our questions are poor in terms of quality when asking questions. Of course, here we aren't at school.

Comment: This is going in a circle now. You're the one who said you were "shocked" your question was closed. I offered a suggestion on how to ask better questions, and then explained why you'd have better luck asking better questions. And now you're saying you don't know what a "quality" question is. Just (a) give context, (b) show research, (c) elaborate on why you're confused - same thing I said five days ago. Maybe all questions have some merit, but some questions are presented much better than others, there's no escaping that. Ignore that reality if you want to - but be ready to be "shocked" again.

Comment: @J.R.: thanks for information. I have to leave now. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Chris'ssister: Well, life gets in the way like that sometimes.